# Cannot unlocked android key with Phonegap API

Tags: javascript, ajax, phonegap-build, phonegap

Hhi, i try to unlock my android keys with the phonegap WRITE API and more precisely with this method: https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/keys/android/257852?auth_token=mytoken

This method returns :

```
{  
    "id":257852,  
    "title":"****",  
    "platform":"android",  
    "created_at":"2017-07-06 01:42:56 -0700",  
    "last_used":"2017-07-11 06:00:33 -0700",  
    "link":"/api/v1/keys/android/257852",  
    "default":false,  
    "alias":"****",  
    "locked":true  
}
```

The problem is that suddenly my key is not unlock as you can see in the return and also on the web interface of build.

I do this request with javascript and jquery ajax :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/keys/android/257852",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password")); 
    },
    type: 'PUT',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    processData: false,
    data: '{"key_pw":"pass","keystore_pw":"pass"}',
    success: function (data) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function(){
      alert("Cannot get data");
    }
});
```

I do not understand what i do wrong...

Thank you for your help and sorry for my bad english !

EDIT :

Ok my bad.. i just give this to data field :

```
data: '{"key_pw":"pass","keystore_pw":"pass"}',
```

and API need something like that :

```
data: 'data={"key_pw":"pass","keystore_pw":"pass"}',
```